# Duplicate an Existing K8s Pod

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

In a namespace `foo` there is an existing pod running

```
$ kubectl get pods -n foo

NAME                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-1816639685-xejyk    1/1       Running   0          6d3h
```

How can we duplicate the `hello` pod so that we can try out things in this duplicated pod without affecting the original pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the pod manifest using YAML output from kubectl and create a new pod based on that specification.

For example

`kubectl get pod hello-1816639685-xejyk -n foo -o yaml`

You need to use a different name or namespace, since the name must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the naming convention, that pod looks like it's a deployment, so you should be able to scale up an additional replica (or replicas) using

```
kubectl scale deployment/hello-1816639685 --replicas=2
```

However, this is assuming you haven't added something like a persistent disk to the deployment (which then won't work with the additional replica)

Comment: if there's a Service pointing to those pods, and if we want to experiment stuff in that new pod, tnen creating a separate deployment (with its own labels) would make sense. If there's no service nor PVC involved, scaling would be easier indeed.